# Date manipulations using as.POSIXlt

Tags: r, date, posixlt

I am trying to locate the nearest Sunday to today.

I define today as:

```
dt <- as.Date("2014-06-04")
```

I can find the last Sunday by following:

```
dt - as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday
[1] "2014-06-01"
```

I can find the next Sunday by following:

```
dt + as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday
[1] "2014-06-07"
```

Not sure why the following is not working:

```
ifelse(as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday <= 3, 
       dt - as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday, 
       dt + as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday)
[1] 16222
```

I am getting a number: `16222` instead of a date.

Each of the following statements work as expected:

```
as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday
class(as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday)
as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday <= 3
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `ifelse` returns a vector and strips the "POSIX" class from your dates. Why not do

```
dt + ifelse(as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday <= 3, -1, 1) * as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday
```

instead.

Comment: Note that this answer (and all the answers except mine) gives  wrong results if dt is Thu, Fri or Sat..  For example, for `dt <- as.Date("2014-06-05")` it gives  `as.Date("2014-06-09")` which is a Monday, not Sunday.
`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: restore the class attribute by calling e.g.:

```
structure(ifelse(as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday <= 3, 
       dt - as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday, 
       dt + as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday), class="Date")
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use an `ifelse` here, A classic `if/else` will do the job:

```
if(as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday <= 3) dt - as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday else dt + as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday
[1] "2014-06-01"
```

Or even simpler:

```
wday <- as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday 
dt + if(wday<= 3) -wday else wday
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the work around. I had thought of it, but my problem was to understand why `ifelse` statement was not working!!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Try this:

```
wday <- as.POSIXlt(dt)$wday
dt + ifelse(wday <= 3, -wday, 7-wday)
```

This applies the `ifelse` to the number of days added or subtracted.  `ifelse` works well with plain numbers but not with complex types like `"Date"` class so this avoids the application of `ifelse` to `"Date"` class objects.

Note that if `wday > 3` then we want to add `7-wday` and not `wday` (as in the question).

The solution here continues to work even if `dt` is a vector of dates.

**2)** Note that the second line of the answer in (1) could alternately be written the following way which first computes the last Sunday (`dt-wday`) and adds 7 to get the next Sunday if its past Wednesday in the week.

```
dt - wday + ifelse(wday > 3, 7, 0)
```

**3)** Yet another way to express this is:

```
dt - wday + 7 * (wday > 3)
```